Hamiltonian is unbounded from below in only one coordinate system
I'm studying a complex scalar field theory in a spatially flat FLRW background. Using the standard conformal time metric $$ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(dr^2 - r^2 d\Omega_2^2)$$ (where $a$ is the scale factor), we obtain a Hamiltonian density of the form $$\mathcal H = \left| \dot\phi\right |^2 + \frac{1}{a^2} \left | \nabla \phi \right | + U(\left | \phi \right |^2).$$ This is clearly bounded from below. However, when we make the transition to physical coordinates, that is $r = \frac{\bar r}{a}$ (provided we work in a spherical chart), the metric becomes $$ds^2 = (1- \bar r^2 H^2)dt^2 + 2\bar r Hdr dt - d\bar r^2 - \bar r^2 d\Omega_2^2,$$  (where $H$ is the hubble paramenter $\frac{\dot a}{a}$) in which case the Hamiltonian we derive is $$\mathcal H = \left |\dot \phi \right |^2 + (1-r^2H^2) \phi ' + \cdots$$ where the other parts are irrelevant. Now this is extremely problematic, since now the Hamiltonian is unbounded from below, and the lowest energy state has $r = \infty$, which is problematic since we are considering solitonic solutions. The question is, how can we remedy this situation in order to actually work with this Hamiltonian and metric?
